# Pandas melt single column level

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical-data

I need to melt the top column level [6,3,4] of the following dataframe while preserving the value columns [a,b,c] and the sorting of the id columns [index,key]. In other words, as with melt, the variable column [6,3,4] should be the outer hierarchical level.

```
np.random.seed(1)
( pd.DataFrame
    ( { (i,j):np.arange(10) + (i*ord(j))
        for i in [6,3,4] for j in ["a","b","c"]
      }
    , index=np.random.randint(10,size=10)
    )
. rename_axis("key")
. reset_index().reset_index()
)
```

```
  index key    6              3              4
               a    b    c    a    b    c    a    b    c
0     0   5  582  588  594  291  294  297  388  392  396
1     1   8  583  589  595  292  295  298  389  393  397
2     2   9  584  590  596  293  296  299  390  394  398
3     3   5  585  591  597  294  297  300  391  395  399
4     4   0  586  592  598  295  298  301  392  396  400
5     5   0  587  593  599  296  299  302  393  397  401
6     6   1  588  594  600  297  300  303  394  398  402
7     7   7  589  595  601  298  301  304  395  399  403
8     8   6  590  596  602  299  302  305  396  400  404
9     9   9  591  597  603  300  303  306  397  401  405
```

I had originally discarded the following as I was under the impression it would not preserve the sort order of the other columns. After learning about `sort_remaining=False`, now I wonder if the sort order of the other columns is guaranteed to be preserved? *Edit: It should be with the stable algorithm, per the linked numpy documentation.*

```
( b.rename_axis(["l1","l2"], axis=1)
. set_index(["index","key"])
. stack("l1")
. sort_index(level="l1", sort_remaining=False, kind="stable")
. reset_index()
)
```

That said, I'm not impressed with the above as unlike `melt` it doesn't preserve the column order. There is `reindex` which requires `swaplevel` but I'm not sure if that's stable either. Also, very complicated.

```
( b.rename_axis(["l1","l2"], axis=1)
. set_index(["index","key"])
. pipe
  ( lambda df: df
  . stack("l1")
  . swaplevel(0,"l1")
  . reindex
    ( df.columns.get_level_values(0).drop_duplicates()
    , level="l1"
    )
  . swaplevel("l1",-1)
  )
. reset_index()
)
```

Expected output:

```
l2  index  key  l1    a    b    c
0       0    5   6  582  588  594
1       1    8   6  583  589  595
2       2    9   6  584  590  596
3       3    5   6  585  591  597
4       4    0   6  586  592  598
5       5    0   6  587  593  599
6       6    1   6  588  594  600
7       7    7   6  589  595  601
8       8    6   6  590  596  602
9       9    9   6  591  597  603
10      0    5   3  291  294  297
11      1    8   3  292  295  298
12      2    9   3  293  296  299
13      3    5   3  294  297  300
14      4    0   3  295  298  301
15      5    0   3  296  299  302
16      6    1   3  297  300  303
17      7    7   3  298  301  304
18      8    6   3  299  302  305
19      9    9   3  300  303  306
20      0    5   4  388  392  396
21      1    8   4  389  393  397
22      2    9   4  390  394  398
23      3    5   4  391  395  399
24      4    0   4  392  396  400
25      5    0   4  393  397  401
26      6    1   4  394  398  402
27      7    7   4  395  399  403
28      8    6   4  396  400  404
29      9    9   4  397  401  405
```

Comment: Will you please add a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: kindly add a `np.random.seed(123)` , so that the randomised data is reproducible/consistent